# Table clustered-index and partitioning in innoDB

Tags: innodb, partitioning, clustered-index

I have a table with 45 columns, 3 of which are relevant:

```
table Transactions(tr_id : int primary key, client : int, tr_date : datetime);
```

- The **inserts** to the table are done `client-by-client`
- The **selects** from the table are mostly done based on `tr_date`

As I read innoDB when inserting re-arranges the data on disk based on the primary key which is `tr_id`. This would mean that neither my inserts nor my selects are benefited by this arrangement.

Inserts are horribly slow and getting slower as the table grows (currently 34,000,000 rows - 36GB)

I want to explore the clustering and partitioning options, but innoDB clusters based on primary key and doesn't allow partitioning on columns that are not part of the primary key.

Is including `tr_date` in the primary key a correct approach? Is there another option I should explore?